# Creating user editable chunk or snippet in ModX

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, chunks

I'm trying to create a chunk or a snippet a user can edit without touching the code. I thought it would be the best to include the content of a page since the pages use an editor. Can anyone tell me how I can accomplish this? Or tell me the best way to do it?

Comment: Why chunk? Why not resource field or tv?

Comment: If you can tell me how. I can try that. That would be awesome

Comment: For what purposes you need this?

Comment: I want to make sure a user can only edit text and dont see any html. So it needs an editor.

Comment: This explain nothing.

Comment: I have created 3 chunks to use in the template. The chunks have text and I want that a user can edit that text without touching the code. Only edit the text

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up permissions for editors to be able to view and edit chunks but not templates.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create, for example, a footer chunk with 3 editable regions.

I would do this by dedicating 3 resources for each editable region. Have the user make their changes via TinyMCE in these 3 resources (perhaps nest them in parent labled accordingly, eg: "Footer Columns"). Make sure they're hidden from menus so they don't come up by mistake.

Then use getResources within your chunk to display each. Eg:

```
<div class="footerchunk">
[[getResources?
  &resources=`45,46,47`
  &tpl=`footerColItem`
  &depth=`0`
  &limit=`3`
  &includeContent=`1`
  &showHidden=`0`
]]
</div>
```

Note that the resources in my example would correspond to the resources your using to allow the users to enter the text.

You would be required to build a `footerColItem` chunk, perhaps something like:

```
<div class="footercol">
  [[+content]]
</div>
```

Note also the use of &showHidden=`0`

This is all from memory, so can't guarantee this will work straight away. Look at https://docs.modx.com/extras/revo/getresources for more info